# EF Core ChangeTracker Shows modified item as unchange and untouched item as modified. Could not save the entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have some model classes as follows:

```
[NotMapped]
public class MyBaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAtUtc { get; }
    public RecordState RecordState { get; set; } = RecordState.Enabled;

    public MyBaseEntity() 
    { 
         CreatedAtUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}

public enum RecordState 
{
    Enabled,
    Deleted,
    Locked
}
    
public class Company : MyBaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public List<Rate> Rates { get; set; } = new();
}

public class Rate: MyBaseEntity
{
    public Company Master { get; set; } = new();
    public List<RateItem> RateItems { get; set; } = new();
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class RateItem: MyBaseEntity
{
    public Rate Rate { get; set; } = new();
    public Company Company { get; set; } = new();
    public decimal PctCharges { get; set; } = 0m;
    public decimal FixCharges { get; set; } = 0m;
    public decimal MinCharges { get; set; } = 0m;
}
```

I have two function to in my repository to get related data as follow:

```
public async Task<T?> GetEntityAsync<T>(ExpressionStarter<T> predicate) where T: MyBaseEntity
{
    return await _context.Set<T>().Where(predicate).FirstOrDefaultAsync();  
}

public async Task LoadRelatedEntity<T>(T entity, List<string> navigations) where T: MyBaseEntity
{
    var properties = _context.Entry<T>(entity).Metadata;
    var _navigateioins = properties.GetNavigations();

    foreach (var nav in _navigateioins)
        if (nav != null && navigations.Contains(nav.Name))
        {
            await _context.Entry<T>(entity).Collection(nav.Name).LoadAsync();
        }
}
```

In my blazor page, I get the `Company` entity and then load the respective `Rates` and `RateItems`. Everything works fine. I can also add a new record too using EF Core.

The problem is that after I finished editing and save to DB, all properties of the loaded company save correctly except the `RateItems` collection.

```
_context.Update<Company>(company);

foreach(var rate in company.Rates)
{
    _context.Update<Rate>(rate);

    foreach(var item in rate.RateItems)
         _context.Update<RateItem>(item);
}

var acceptAllChangesOnSuccess = true;
await SaveChangeAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
```

I have already attached the `Rates` and `RateItems` collections in to the context. I used the `ChangeTracker.DebugView` to check the modified entities:

```
**RateItem {Id: 14} Unchanged**
  Id: 14 PK
  CreatedAtUtc: '2022/8/2 2:47:10'
  FixCharge: 0.00000
  MinCharge: 0.00000
  CompanyId: 4 FK
  PctCharge: 0.02000
  RateId: 4 FK
  **RecordState: 'Deleted' Originally 'Enabled'**
  Company: {Id: 4}
  Rate: {Id: 4}

RateItem {Id: 15} Modified
  Id: 15 PK
  CreatedAtUtc: '2022/8/2 2:47:52' Modified
  FixCharge: 0.00000 Modified
  MinCharge: 0.00000 Modified
  CompanyId: 4 FK Modified
  PctCharge: 0.03000 Modified
  RateId: 4 FK Modified
  RecordState: 'Enabled' Modified
  Company: {Id: 4}
  Rate: {Id: 4}
```

The tracker identify the changes. I can't figure out

For RateItem {Id:14} is Unchanged, but RecordState of it is changed already.

For RateItem {Id:15} i didn't change anything, but it shows that Modified.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks @marc_s for helping me improve the question

Comment: `Update` actually marks an _entire graph_ of related entities as `Modified`. [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/explicit-tracking#updating-existing-entities). There is no need to traverse through child objects.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Thx. I read the docs again and tried to remove the update. Problem is still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I don't trust `DebugView` myself. I'm pretty sure there's a bug in there.

I just set a date on a column that was `null` and I see:

```
FreeShippingProgram {FreeShippingProgramId: 4238935} Unchanged
LastMaintenanceDt: '9/27/2023 5:05:59 PM' Originally <null>
```

Then I look at `Context.Entry(entity).State` and it is `Modified`

THEN I go back to `DebugView` and now it's showing `Modified` too! I didn't save or do anything.

```
FreeShippingProgram {FreeShippingProgramId: 4238935} Modified
```

How is that possible?